# Pass deleted element ID into function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a complete newbie in javascript, so sorry for silly question ...
I've got an html page with the elements on it. elements has boottsrap dropdown buttons, to delete, lock and edit functions. the question is how i can pass ID of deleted element into javascript function, that this function let me do appropriate changes in the json and database. here is the function what I've wrote, but for some reason it doesn't work and returns with the NaN ... any ideas what is wrong with it ?

html example for the element:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="droptrue" id="sortable1" style="margin-left: 2em">
      <div id="1B">
        <ul>
          <li class="ui-state-default">
            <textarea cols="18" id="1" name="1"
              placeholder="Type here .." rows="3" spellcheck="true" 
              style="overflow: auto;resize: none; resize:vertical;"
              tabindex="4">
            </textarea>

            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Action
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a class="del" href="#" id="1">Delete</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a class="lok" href="#">Lock</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a class="edt" href="#">Edit</a>
                </li>

                <li class="divider"></li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#">Share</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
function removeDummy( n ) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(n);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
}

$(function(){

  $('.del').click(function() {
    var id = parseInt(this.id.substring(4));
    alert(id);
    removeDummy("1B");
    return false;
  });
});
```

can't figure out what is wrong with it, any help please ?!
Thanx

Comment: `id`s should be unique.

Comment: also why are you doing `substring(4)` as far as I can see the id of your del is `1` so that substring wouldn't work.  Perhaps you should be using data-attributes rather than multiple same ids

Comment: Thanks oGeez, looks like I don't need substring (4) at all ... will try to figure out what to do next . Thank you, you save me a lot of time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as oGeez says, id should be unique and you could potentially run into a problem. So, use data-id and access through jquery `.data()` function.

You alert is returning NaN though cause this.id is null. this is not the jQuery object either so you need to wrap this in `$(this)` then you can get the id with `$(this).data('id')`. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/28etb/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'm complete newbie so have to learn JavaScript more and harder !